# Jquery .post and .append how to put some information in to different div's

Tags: jquery, .post

Hi am working with laravel+Jquery and I am using POST method to send input information to controller by Jquery .post().
And what controller return is html information. That information is put  to the same page with .append():

```js
$('#getRequest').submit(function () {
                var town = $('#town').val();
                var key = $('#key').val();


                $.post('getRequest', { town:town, key:key},function (data) {
                    $('#getRequestData').append(date);
                    $('#nav-tabContent').append(data);
                });
            });
```

The problem is: I want to filter that information and to put into different page parts. I tryed to use .filter() or .has(), but I failed. 
I want to put some .append(date) information into #getRequestData'.
And to do the same to put antoher .append(date) information to $('#nav-tabContent').append(data);.

What I should to use or to do, please?

Comment: two things: is it `date` or `data` ? the other thing is why using .append(). Will .html() work for you ? But, to determine that you might want to say if data is html/a json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the response in `$()` and query it for what you want using `find()` the same way you would if it was in the page.

Something like:

```
$.post('getRequest', { town:town, key:key},function (data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $('#getRequestData').append($data.find('someSelector'));
    $('#nav-tabContent').append($data.find('anotherSelector'));
});
```

The selectors you use would depend on what is in the response html

Answer (score 0):

Just stop default form processing:

```
$('#getRequest').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var town = $('#town').val();
            var key = $('#key').val();

            $.post('getRequest', { town:town, key:key},function (data) {
                $('#getRequestData').append(data);
                $('#nav-tabContent').append(data);
            });

            return false;
});
```

and do not confuse `data` and `date`